# Getting a ValueError when making a NamedTemporaryFile in python

Tags: python, temporary-files

haven't found a solution to this through searching existing questions, here goes:

New-ish to python. Trying to make a temporary file using the `tempfile` package. Here is the line of code that is failing with a `ValueError`:

`(temp_file, self.bucket) = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.py', prefix='Custom_', dir=[mydir], delete=False)`

I'm getting this ValueError when I run my script:

`ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack`

Why?

Comment: Sidenote (existing answer covers main problem): Did you really pass `dir=[mydir]`, or is `[mydir]` supposed to be a placeholder? You don't pass `dir` as a `list`, which is what the brackets would do.

Comment: That is just a placeholer. I did have a valid dir path in there. :) @ShadowRanger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()` doesn't return the filename, only the handle. You need to access the name attribute in order to get the filename.

Comment: I understand that part, but I guess what you mean is I don't want to have `(temp_file, self.bucket)` before the `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()`? Maybe just `self.bucket` instead?

Comment: Nvm, ^ that fixed my problem. Thanks!

Comment: The confusion is probably because `mkstemp` is mentioned repeatedly by `TemporaryFile`'s docs, and `mkstemp` returns handle and name. But `TemporaryFile` and `NamedTemporaryFile` are higher level types that have return values like `open`, not low level APIs like `mkstemp`.